# Expected mime type application/xml but got text/html

Tags: java, solr, mime

I was trying solrj in eclipse but I got this error message:

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Expected mime type application/xml but got text/html
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.executeMethod(HttpSolrServer.java:512)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:210)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:206)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:91)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:301)
    at pack.SearchServlet.service(SearchServlet.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Below is my code:

```
queryString=request.getParameter("query");
keywords=queryString.split(" ");

server=new HttpSolrServer(url);
server.setMaxRetries(1);
server.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
server.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
server.setSoTimeout(1000);
server.setDefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost(100);
server.setMaxTotalConnections(100);
server.setFollowRedirects(false);
server.setAllowCompression(true);

query=new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("title:"+keywords[0]+" OR content"+keywords[0]);
query.setStart(0);
query.setRows(8);

query.setHighlight(true);
query.addHighlightField("content");
query.addHighlightField("title");

queryResponse=server.query(query);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by extending `XMLResponseParser`, overriding `getContentType`, and using it as response parser.

```
protected class QESXMLResponseParser extends XMLResponseParser {
    public QESXMLResponseParser() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return "text/xml; charset=UTF-8";
    }
}
```

Then, only change your code to use the "new parser"

```
server.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
server.setParser(new QESXMLResponseParser());
server.setSoTimeout(1000);
```

Comment: Hello @SarahTammam, this snippet is about 4 years old, your version may differ from the one we used at that time. I'm not working with SolR from years... I can't help you much more, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

My guess that you're using a fairly modern solrj to talk to a fairly old solr. [This bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5532) references the problem with too-strict mime-type comparisons.

The easiest (but probably not best) solution is likely to downgrade your solrj files. I don't know exactly when the problem hit, but I know my stuff works with `solr-solrj-4.3.1.jar` running against a solr 1.4 installation.

Answer (score -1):

Look on the Solr server console or log files. Most likely you got the URL wrong and getting back an HTML error page back instead of the Solr response. There should be a specific error in the server logs.

Comment: An HTML page would come back text/html; this is likely https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5532